# How to use a file name in move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, html

My goal is to create a video, and then upload the video onto a file server. I can create the video (which is in the form of a BLOB) and I can convert the BLOB into a file. Next I want to upload that file onto the server. The following html and php code uploads a file to a server. Can I substitute $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] with the file name that has been created from the BLOB? Is there a simpler way of achieving my goal?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="upload_.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file"  name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>


<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
//$target_file = "myFile.jpg";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]). " has been uploaded.";
     } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

Comment: You can (and probably have to) put an filename into the second argument of `move_uploaded_file`, so I don't really see your problem?

Comment: Using the name from the upload is a bad idea. What if two different users each upload a file named `MyVideo.jpg`? When the second user uploads their file, it will replace the first one.

Comment: This is not an issue as I will be assigning a unique file name.

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];` returns the temporary file name of the file on the server.

`$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];` returns original name of the uploaded file from yours computer

You can't substitute tmp_name to name on 1st parameter in `move_uploaded_file`